# appending multi index columns into empty dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Following Problem I got a DataFrame like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex(levels=[["foo","baa"],["x","y","z"]], labels=[[0,0,0,1,1,1],[0,1,2,0,1,2]]), index=[0,1,2,3], data=np.random.rand(4,6))

         foo                           baa                    
          x         y         z         x         y         z
0  0.263780  0.942880  0.176744  0.914854  0.920735  0.573692
1  0.601317  0.584691  0.288536  0.832064  0.095142  0.186045
2  0.807323  0.075620  0.399703  0.936894  0.168441  0.468984
3  0.871293  0.324817  0.395784  0.133541  0.365586  0.615219
```

And I want to get say foo out of it into a new DataFrame completly empty constructed like this:

```
r_df = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

it should look like this:

```
         foo
          x         y         z
0  0.263780  0.942880  0.176744
1  0.601317  0.584691  0.288536
2  0.807323  0.075620  0.399703
3  0.871293  0.324817  0.395784
```

How I tryed to do it was like this:

```
for label in df.columns.levels[0]:
    data = df[label]
    for row in data.index:
        r_df.loc[row,(label,"x")] = data["x"]
        r_df.loc[row,(label,"y")] = data["y"]
        r_df.loc[row,(label,"z")] = data["z"]
```

I thought this could work because multi index can be referenced by tubles but it didnt.

Comment: Simply use print(df['foo']).....You will get foo part.

Comment: that is not the problam I need to not print but work on the data

Comment: You can create new dataframe out of the existing one :- dfnew=df['foo']

Comment: You can also use `r_df = df.xs('foo', axis=1, level=0, drop_level=False)` if you do want to keep it as a multiindex.

Comment: If you are satisfied by answer please mark it accepted...let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: and how do i preserve the multiindex and also be able to add more columns if needed i have about 83 foo baa columns and i need to extract the by name and add the m to the new dataframe where after that i can do some work on the data

Comment: @gyx-hh yeah that is a good thing and it helps me alot now to the problem i have to not make a new but append it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following using `df.xs` to select from multiIndex and keep level:

```
r_df = df.xs('foo', axis=1, level=0, drop_level=False)
```

If you want to append a new column under `foo` then you can do:

```
df.loc[:,('foo','m')] = 0
```

if you want to a append a new column in `level=0` (same level as `foo`)

```
# with no col in level 1
df.loc[:, 'bar'] = 0 

# with col in level 0 and 1
df.loc[:,('bar','m')] = 0
```